# Change keyboard shortcuts with terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu and I would like to use bash/terminal to change keyboard shortcuts. And help is appreciated!

Comment: Look in to gsettings, i.e (gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Control><Primary><Alt>k']")

Comment: I have KDE not GNOME

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think to try out the command, that doesn't have access to all of the shortcuts in Shortcust and Gestures though